# Repeating values in a "group by" pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
     email   cat  class_price
0   email1@gmail.com  cat1            1
1   email2@gmail.com  cat2            2
2   email3@gmail.com  cat2            4
3   email1@gmail.com  cat2            4
4   email2@gmail.com  cat2            1
5   email3@gmail.com  cat1            3
6   email1@gmail.com  cat1            2
7   email2@gmail.com  cat2            1
8   email3@gmail.com  cat2            4
9   email1@gmail.com  cat2            2
10  email2@gmail.com  cat3            1
11  email3@gmail.com  cat1            1
```

And I want to group by email and by class_price, for each line I want to take the max of class_price.

I'm using:

```
test_df2 = test_df.groupby(['email','cat'])['class_price'].max()
```

The output is:

```
email             cat 
email1@gmail.com  cat1    2
                  cat2    4
email2@gmail.com  cat2    2
                  cat3    1
email3@gmail.com  cat1    3
                  cat2    4
```

But how can I get a result where even grouped columns retain repeated values,such that it can be be written as a proper table with all the values:

```
email             cat      maxvalue 
email1@gmail.com    cat2     2
email1@gmail.com    cat1     2
email3@gmail.com    cat3     3
```

Note: example output isn't compatible with example input just written to explain the idea.

Comment: Can you add output from input data? Or maybe change input data for better understanding?

Answer (score 8):

You can just reset the index, putting data in columns.

```
In [1]: print (test_df2.reset_index(name='maxvalue').to_string(index=False))
           email   cat     maxvalue
email1@gmail.com  cat1            2
email1@gmail.com  cat2            4
email2@gmail.com  cat2            2
email2@gmail.com  cat3            1
email3@gmail.com  cat1            3
email3@gmail.com  cat2            4
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try `reset_index` as in other answer or you can try below -

```
test_df2 = test_df.groupby(['email','cat'], as_index=False)['class_price'].max()
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMO as it highlights the fact that the groupby function has a parameter that can be set for just this reason.